# Align icon with text in navbar Bootstrap 4

Tags: text, icons, alignment, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to place the icon before the text in the navigation button. However, it always appears above.
Also, the icon must be aligned vertically with the text.
This must be really easy to correct but can not figure it out.
Any feedback is highly appreciated.

What should look like:
[image]

What happens:
[image]

```css
.nav-link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto w-100">
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/backoffice/jobs" routerLinkActive="active">
        <img src="/assets/icons/B_Hammer_Gray.svg" class="iconos " alt="hammer">
        <h4>Test 1</h4>
      </a>
    </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/backoffice/contractors" routerLinkActive="active" style="display:block">
          <img src="/assets/icons/B_Toolbox_Gray.svg" class="iconos" alt="toolbox">
          <h4>Test 2</h4>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/backoffice/jobs" routerLinkActive="active">
          <img src="/assets/icons/B_Hammer_Gray.svg" class="iconos " alt="hammer">
          <h4>Test 3</h4>
        </a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `class="d-inline"` to your h4 elements like so:

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto w-100">
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/backoffice/jobs" routerLinkActive="active">
           <img src="/assets/icons/B_Hammer_Gray.svg" class="iconos " alt="hammer">
           <h4 class="d-inline">Test 1</h4>
       </a>
   </li>

   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/backoffice/contractors" routerLinkActive="active" style="display:block">
           <img src="/assets/icons/B_Toolbox_Gray.svg" class="iconos" alt="toolbox">
           <h4 class="d-inline">Test 2</h4>
       </a>
   </li>

   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/backoffice/jobs" routerLinkActive="active">
           <img src="/assets/icons/B_Hammer_Gray.svg" class="iconos " alt="hammer">
           <h4 class="d-inline">Test 3</h4>
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

`h4`s (and `h1`s etc.) are normally block level elements that's why they wrap.

Comment: And if you wanted to avoid using native Bootstrap classes as shown above, you'll have to increase the specificity in order for your custom css to work. In other words, you'll need to use this: `.nav-link h4 { display: inline-block; }`